# Zero locus of a general section

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, locus

I just need one precision about the definition of zero locus of a **general** section of a vector bundle.

> I know that if the $s$ is a section of a vector bundle $E$ on a scheme $X$, the zero locus of $s$ is the set $Z(s)$ which ideal sheaf is the image of the morphism $\mathcal E^{\vee}\rightarrow \mathcal O_X$, where $\mathcal E$ is the corresponding locally free sheaf to $E$.

So, I think that the zero locus of a general section is the zero locus of a section in a Zariski open subset in the space of global sections of $E$. Right?
Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that would be my interpretation. Usually, you will have some Zariski closed condition on sections $s\in\Gamma(X,\mathcal{E})$. Then saying a "general" section of $\mathcal{E}$ has a property means that outside of a closed subset of $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{E})$ the property holds.

e.g. a general section of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\Bbb{P}^1$ does not vanish at a given $P\in \Bbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I need to rewrite your example to know if I understand it well, In that case I understand that the set $S_P:=\{ s\in \Gamma(\mathbb P^1,\mathcal O(1))\ ; \ s(P)=0\}$ is a closed subset  of $\Gamma(\mathbb P^1,\mathcal O(1))$ for a fixed point $P\in \mathbb P^1$. So, if $s$ is a general section of $\mathcal O(1)$ then $s\notin S_(P)$. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The condition on sections of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is given by evaluation at $P$. This defines a linear functional $\Gamma(\Bbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}(1))\to k$ and so the sections _not_ satisfying this property are the complement of a hyperplane.